# Word count for multiple .txt files in linux

Tags: command-line

I need to find the words in multiple .txt files using a linux cli.
Currently I am using the following command:

```
cat *.txt|wc -w
```

I have made a test directory to practice the command and it seems to work for each individual .txt file but it fails to do it properly for all the .txt files.
I have a directory with 5 files in which 4 of them contain each 5 words and 1 is emtpy.
For the individual `cat textfile.txt|wc -w` it gives the right answer.
But for the count it gives 17 when it should be (4 times 5 + 0 times 0 =) 20
Can someone tell my why the count given is 17 while the real count is 20?

Comment: cannot reproduce, you will need to add your input files.

Comment: These links have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can run

```
wc -w *.txt
```

This will give you the word count for each file and a total sum in the last row.

As it turned out, OPs issue was a missing newline in one of the files. This caused `cat *txt` to combine multiple words into one and therefore resulting in a wrong count.
The command above is more robust in this situation as it processes each file individually.

Comment: I found out why, there was no seperator so the last character from the previous file got attached to the first character of the following file.

Comment: Thanks @wayne_yux I have been struggling with it the whole morning with a deadline coming up. Such a stupid small thing your solution works, HERO:)

Comment: If you put a newline or space at the end of all the files (this happens automatically with `echo` for example), you could just use the command in the question

Comment: @pLumo doing a `cat` first will give you only the total number of words. If you run `wc -w` on all files, you will get a number per file. That makes debugging way easier. As it seems, OPs issue was that there was no newline at the end of one file. That would cause `cat` to combine some words. If you handle the files individually, this does not occur

Comment: true true :-) makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the final lines of your files are not properly newline-terminated, so that when you `cat` them, the first word of the next file gets appended to last word of the previous file:

Ex. given

```
steeldriver@pc:~$ printf 'foo\nbar\nbaz\nbam\nboo' | tee {1..4}.txt
foo
bar
baz
bam
boosteeldriver@pc:~$ printf '' > 5.txt
```

then

```
steeldriver@pc:~$ wc -w {1..5}.txt
 5 1.txt
 5 2.txt
 5 3.txt
 5 4.txt
 0 5.txt
20 total
```

but

```
steeldriver@pc:~$ cat {1..5}.txt | wc -w
17
```